# glassfishの単体テストをArquillianで実行した際、Jbatchが終了後に動作しDBアクセスエラーを起こす

Tags: java8

概要：
JavaEEでプロジェクトを開発中、解決できないエラーが発生しました。
Jbatchが意図しないタイミングで動作し、DBアクセスエラーを起こします。

環境：

- Windows 8.1
- netbeans 8.0.2
- JDK 1.8.0_25
- JAVAEE 7.0
- Glassfish 4.1
- PostgreSQL 9.2.7

構成：（最小構成を構築してエラー再現を確認）

- src/main/java/local/arquilliansample/jbatch/jobBatchlet.java
- src/main/java/local/arquilliansample/SampleBean.java
- src/main/java/resources/META-INF/batch-jobs/jobBatchlet.xml
- src/test/java/local/arquilliansample/SampleBeanTest.java

詳細：
作成した単体テストプログラムを実行すると、テストプログラム終了後に
Jbatchが起動し、DBへアクセスを試みますが下記エラーにて接続できません。
（テスト自体は完了後なので単体テストはグリーンで終了する）

```
情報: RAR7094: __xa_jdbc_ra shutdown successful.
2 24, 2015 9:19:01 午前 com.ibm.jbatch.container.services.impl.JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl logException
重大: FAILED GETTING DATABASE CONNECTION; Exception stack trace: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: This Managed Connection is not valid as the physical connection is not usable
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:121)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.services.impl.JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.getConnectionToDefaultSchema(JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.java:340)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.services.impl.JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.isDerby(JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.java:171)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.services.impl.JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.init(JDBCPersistenceManagerImpl.java:132)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl$ServiceLoader.getService(ServicesManagerImpl.java:358)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl$ServiceLoader.access$300(ServicesManagerImpl.java:341)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl.getService(ServicesManagerImpl.java:261)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl.getPersistenceManagerService(ServicesManagerImpl.java:292)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.BatchKernelImpl.<init>(BatchKernelImpl.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl$ServiceLoader._loadService(ServicesManagerImpl.java:404)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl$ServiceLoader._loadServiceHelper(ServicesManagerImpl.java:377)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl$ServiceLoader.getService(ServicesManagerImpl.java:357)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl$ServiceLoader.access$300(ServicesManagerImpl.java:341)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl.getService(ServicesManagerImpl.java:261)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl.getBatchKernelService(ServicesManagerImpl.java:307)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.api.impl.JobOperatorImpl.<init>(JobOperatorImpl.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime$1.run(BatchRuntime.java:52)
        at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime$1.run(BatchRuntime.java:47)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime.getJobOperator(BatchRuntime.java:47)
        at org.glassfish.batch.spi.impl.BatchRuntimeHelper.event(BatchRuntimeHelper.java:218)
        at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl$1.run(EventsImpl.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: This Managed Connection is not valid as the physical connection is not usable
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:319)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:196)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:171)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:166)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:114)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: This Managed Connection is not valid as the physical connection is not usable
        at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.ConnectorAllocator.fillInResourceObjects(ConnectorAllocator.java:194)
        at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:488)
        at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:245)
        at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:170)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:307)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: This Managed Connection is not valid as the physical connection is not usable
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionImpl.checkIfValid(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:756)
        at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ManagedConnectionImpl.java:443)
        at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.ConnectorAllocator.fillInResourceObjects(ConnectorAllocator.java:189)
        ... 47 more

2 24, 2015 9:19:01 午前 com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl$ServiceLoader _loadServiceHelper
重大: Could not instantiate service: com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.BatchKernelImpl due to exception:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2 24, 2015 9:19:01 午前 org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl$1 run
警告: Exception while dispatching an event
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.batch.operations.JobOperator: Provider com.ibm.jbatch.container.api.impl.JobOperatorImpl could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime$1.run(BatchRuntime.java:52)
        at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime$1.run(BatchRuntime.java:47)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime.getJobOperator(BatchRuntime.java:47)
        at org.glassfish.batch.spi.impl.BatchRuntimeHelper.event(BatchRuntimeHelper.java:218)
        at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl$1.run(EventsImpl.java:123)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not instantiate service com.ibm.jbatch.container.impl.BatchKernelImpl due to exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl$ServiceLoader._loadServiceHelper(ServicesManagerImpl.java:385)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl$ServiceLoader.getService(ServicesManagerImpl.java:357)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl$ServiceLoader.access$300(ServicesManagerImpl.java:341)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl.getService(ServicesManagerImpl.java:261)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.servicesmanager.ServicesManagerImpl.getBatchKernelService(ServicesManagerImpl.java:307)
        at com.ibm.jbatch.container.api.impl.JobOperatorImpl.<init>(JobOperatorImpl.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
        ... 13 more
```

設定ファイル等は以下になります。
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>local</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArquillianSample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ArquillianSample</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- open arquillian -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <!-- close -->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- open arquillian -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- close -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

jobBatchlet.java

```
package local.arquilliansample.jbatch;

import javax.batch.api.Batchlet;

public class JobBatchlet implements Batchlet {

    @Override
    public String process() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("[Batchlet] process");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("[Batchlet] stop");
    }
}
```

SampleBean.java

```
package local.arquilliansample;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class SampleBean {

    public void writeMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

jobBatchlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job id="jobBatchlet" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="1.0">
    <step id="step1">
        <batchlet ref="arquilliansample.jbatch.JobBatchlet" />
    </step>
</job>
```

SampleBeanTest.java

```
package local.arquilliansample;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SampleBeanTest {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addClass(SampleBean.class)
                .addClass(SampleBeanTest.class);
        System.out.println(archive.toString(true));
        return archive;
    }

    @Inject
    private SampleBean bean;

    @Test
    public void testWriteMessage() {
        bean.writeMessage("hello world");

        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

またエラーが出るのは確実ではなく、3回中２回位の頻度です。

どなたか解決方法をご存じでしたらご教授頂きたいと思います。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

追記：
コードブロックが派手に崩れていて申し訳ありません・・・
このマークダウン形式をまだよくわかっていないため後ほど修正します。

Answer (score 1):

GlassFish の Embedded コンテナを利用して Java SE 環境での実行になるかと
思いますので、下記の URL をご参考にされてみては如何でしょうか。

http://yoshio3.com/2014/02/18/jbatchjsr-352-on-java-se-%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83/

特に、2 番目の設定を行われてみては如何でしょうか？
バッチ・コンテナは各種情報を DB(デフォルトでは Java DB)に保存しますので、
DB に接続できない、もしくは DB が停止している状況ですと、正しく動作しないかと想定します。

2. Batch コンテナを実行するための設定

次に Batch コンテナを稼働させるためのプロパティの設定を行います。
META-INF ディレクトリ配下に services ディレクトリを作成して
それぞれ下記のファイルを作成してください。

src/META-INF/services/batch-config.properties

JDBC_DRIVER=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
JDBC_URL=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/batchdb;create=true

src/META-INF/services/batch-services.properties
J2SE_MODE=true

以上で基本的には Java SE 環境上で動作させるために必要な設定は完了です。

上記の設定を行った際、
asadmin start-database 等で JavaDB を事前に常時起動しておく必要はあります。GlassFish から Java DB を起動する場合、GlassFish の停止時に Java DB も停止するのでタイミング的に OK/NG の可能性はあるかと思います。

また、EJB を @Inject でインジェクトしていますが、EJB は @EJB でインジェクトして頂ければと思います。

Comment: 寺田様、回答ありがとうございます。  
  
返答が遅れて申し訳ありませんでした。  
参考サイトを読ませて頂いたうえで上記内容を試してみたのですが、  
未だに同様の頻度でエラーが出力されております。  
  
対応内容：  
src/META-INF/services/batch-config.properties  
src/META-INF/services/batch-services.properties  
のファイル作成。  
  
C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1\javadb\bin\startNetworkServer.bat  
によるJavaDBの起動。  

何度かテストを行っているのですが、（ビルドし直した後などの）初回はほぼ成功し2～3回目が落ちます。